# Check if List<List<int>> Contains List<int>

Tags: c#, list

What is the best way to check if a `List<List<int>>` contains a `List<int>` like:

```
List<List<int>> test = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> a = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6};
List<int> b = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6};
test.Add(a);
Debug.Log(test.Contains(b));
```

I know that `Contains()` doesn't check the *contents* of `List<T>`, so I'm looking for an alternative way to determine equivalence.

Comment: Does order matter in you case? For example a= new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6} and b= new List<int>{1,2,4,3,5,6} should return true or false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
test.Any(x => x.All(b.Contains));
```

This will return `true` but it's not exactly correct. It would also return `true` if `b` contains more elements than `1,2,3,4,5,6` (for example `7,8,9`, etc). To fix this you can try `SequenceEqual`:

```
test.Any(x => x.OrderBy(y => y)
    .SequenceEqual(b.OrderBy(z => z)));
```

If you don't want it to return `true` when `b` is unordered (for example `2,1,3,4,5,6`), then don't use `OrderBy`; just use `SequenceEqual`:

```
test.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(b));
```

Comment: +1 for distinction between contains and contains exactly the items and no more.

Comment: thank you very very much!
Finaly I used an unordered list, so thank's for both solution, you made my day :-)

Comment: Of course if this is a common case you may want to use a HashSet or SortedSet instead of a List

Answer (score 0):

The equality of the lists is being compared by reference not by value so `test.Contains(b)` is false for the same reason `a == b` is false. But there is an operator `SequenceEqual` which will compare two lists by their content, such that in your example `a.SequenceEqual(b)` is true, and so therefore you could do:

```
test.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(b))
```

which will return true.